# Tratamento de json em Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Tenho o seguinte retorno JSON de uma página:

```html
{  
   "0":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"45454545454",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "1":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"4",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "2":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"5",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "3":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"45",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "4":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"44",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "status":"success",
   "msgs":5
}
```

São retornos dinâmicos, ou seja, as vezes podem vir 1 ou as vezes 20, logo preciso conseguir pegar todos os indices de cada "array", e pegar os dados dos "sub-arrays"

Comment: Vai vir sempre na sequência 0, 1, 2...?

Comment: sim. sempre nessa sequencia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar `for...in` para iterar o objeto:

```js
var json ={
   "0":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"45454545454",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "1":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"4",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "2":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"5",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "3":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"45",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "4":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"44",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "status":"success",
   "msgs":5
}


for(var item in json){
   console.log(json[item]); // pega os objetos
   for(var val in json[item]){
      console.log(json[item][val]); // pega os valores
   }
}
```

O exemplo acima pega os objetos e seus valores em dois laços. Agora vai depender da forma de como você quer pegar os valores.

Uma outra forma é usando `for` normal usando como valor máximo do laço o valor na chave `msgs`:

```js
var json ={
   "0":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"45454545454",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "1":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"4",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "2":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"5",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "3":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"45",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "4":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"44",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "status":"success",
   "msgs":5
}


for(var x=0; x<json.msgs; x++){
   console.log(json[x]); // pega os objetos
   console.log(json[x].id_user);
   console.log(json[x].contente);
   console.log(json[x].time);
   console.log(json[x].nick);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado. A com o for tradicional funcionou muito bem. Boa tarde.

Answer (score 1):

Tem a possibilidade de usar $each também. Algo mais ou menos dessa forma:

```
var data = [ 
{  
   "0":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"45454545454",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "1":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"4",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "2":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"5",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "3":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"45",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "4":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"44",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "status":"success",
   "msgs":5
}
];


$.each(data, function(a, item) {
  $.each(item, function(i, subitem) {
    if( i > 0 ){
      alert(
        "indice: " + i
        + ", " + 
        "id_user: " + subitem.id_user
        + ", " + 
        "contente: " + subitem.contente
        + ", " + 
        "time: " + subitem.time
        + ", " + 
        "nick: " + subitem.nick );
    }
  });
});
```